# Angular ngx-smart-popover open on condition

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I have the smart popover setup like this with an additional button and shown on click. This is put in it's own component like this:

```
<popover-content #myPopover id="myPopover"  
   placement="bottom" [animation]="true" [closeOnClickOutside]="false" >
// Some content here
</popover-content>
<input type='button' #selectMyPopover [popover]="myPopover" class='btn'
  popoverPlacement="bottom" [popoverOnHover]="false" 
 [popoverCloseOnMouseOutside]="false" [value]='myButton'>
```

And then when I want to use it I include it with the component tag like this:

```
<app-my-popover></app-my-popover>
```

It's great but all examples I've found requires the usage of that additional button like this:

`<input type='button'[popover]="myPopover"...`

I am trying to show the popover based on condition instead of having to click on that button. For example:

```
myMethod()
{
    if(true)
    {
        this.myPopover.open();
    }
}
```

is it possible to open in from the typescript in a similar way on your own instead of using the button?

Comment: Get it as a `ViewChild` and then you can call the open method.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to get a reference to the popover component in your typescript using `ViewChild` as following:

```
@ViewChild('myPopover') myPopover : PopoverContentComponent;
```

then you can access this reference where you want:

```
this.myPopover.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

if you take a look at their source [here](https://github.com/lsqlabs/ngx-smart-popover/blob/master/projects/ngx-smart-popover/src/lib/popover-content.component.ts) there is `show` and `hide` method. Then you need to get reference to that object in your ts file by using `@ViewChild` as below

```
@ViewChild('myPopover') myPopover : PopoverContentComponent;
```

later you can do

```
this.myPopover.show();
```

Comment: The show(); method does not work the same way the standard <input type='button'[popover]="myPopover"... works for me. Should I include something else. Right now the popover is not actually showing even tho the method gets executed.

Comment: @SarthakAgastya what do you mean by it doesnt work the same way? does it show the popover at all? the place is correct?

Comment: Yes that's the thing the popover does not show at all when I call the show() method. Even tho I am able to get the object with @ViewChild as you suggested.

Comment: @SarthakAgastya then could be a bug, if you can create a stackblitz I can recheck it for you to see if something is missed

Comment: @SarthakAgastya Btw the general solution for that kind of needs is to get reference to child and then call the method on it